# How can I make such a style for a container

Tags: flutter

I want to make the container look like this [style container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lr3T6.png) but my container looks like this [my container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dX595.png). How can I do this?

Code :

```
child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
            color: Color(0xffCEFC4C),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topRight: Radius.circular(20))),
        width: 327,
        height: 56,
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Text(
          'SAVE BUTTON',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black,
            fontSize: 16.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use something like this

```
  Material(
          clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
          shape: BeveledRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          topRight: Radius.circular(20.0),
           ),
          ),
           child: Container(
                height: 100,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Color(0xffCEFC4C),
             ),
          ),
        ),
```